# Help with finding a Windows RT port

Tags: nvidia, arm

So far I've been getting a good bit of non-answers by other linux forums for a port (that works) of ubuntu for a Surface RT. I just want a dl link or a detailed walk through on how to make one myself, seeing as I am not a dev. I understand how to install ubuntu, and that's about the extent of my knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no Ubuntu port for Surface RT, though you can run Ubuntu on Surface Pro

Those are completely different types of computers that are entirely incompatible with each other.